# постраничный вывод через ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Есть сайт, в котором в поиск вбиваешь страну.

```html
<?php
  require "includes/config.php";
?>

  <!DOCTYPE html >
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>
      <?php echo $config['title'];?>
    </title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
    <link href="/style/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/style/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="city.php" method="get">
      <input name="search" placeholder="введите страну..." type="text" class="search ">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="поиск"></input>
    </form>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

После нажатия на кнопку данные отправляются на другую страницу и там сравниваются с базой:

```html
<?php
  require "includes/config.php";
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html >
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>
      <?php echo $config['title'];?>
    </title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
    <link href="/style/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/style/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
     $search = $_GET['search'];
     $countrys = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `countrys` WHERE `country` LIKE '%$search%' ");     
     $country = mysqli_fetch_assoc($countrys);          
    }
   ?>
      <ul>
        <?php
   $per_page = 5;
    

    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
     $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
    } else ($page = 1);

    $total_country_id_q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `total_count` FROM `citys` WHERE `country_id`  =  ". $country['id']); 

    $total_country_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_country_id_q);

    $total_country_id = $total_country_id["total_count"]; 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_country_id / $per_page);


    if( $page <= 1 || $page > $total_pages)
    {
     $page = 1;
    }
    $offset = ($per_page * $page) - $per_page;

    $citys = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `citys` WHERE `country_id` = " . $country['id'] . " LIMIT $offset,$per_page ");   

     while(($city = mysqli_fetch_assoc($citys))) 
     {
      echo "<li>" . $city["city"] . "</li>";
     }
  ?>
          <script>
            /////надо правильно сформировать страницу DATA search = '. $country['country'] .' , теряется страна var country из GET(видимо потому что не пришло нажатии кнопки "submit") после перехода на другую страницу и да ссылка так криво формируется, в обычном постраничном она выглядит как(<a href="/city.php?search='. $country['country'] .'&submit='value'&page='.($page - 1).'; ">)
            $(function() {


              $("#next").click(function() {
                var page = <?=$page?>;
                var country = <?=$country['country']?>;
                вот эта переменная пропадает после нажатия на ссылку next
                $.ajax({
                  url: "city.php",
                  type: 'GET',
                  data: "/city.php?search=" + (country) + "&submit='value'&page=" + (page + 1),
                  success: function(html) {

                    $(".content").html(html).hide().fadeIn(300);
                  }

                });
              });

              $("#prev").click(function() {
                var page = <?=$page;?>

                $.ajax({
                  url: 'city.php',
                  type: 'GET',
                  data: "/city.php?search='. $country['country'] .'&submit='.value.'&page=" + (page - 1),
                  success: function(html) {

                    $(".content").html(html).hide().fadeIn(300);
                  }
                });

              });
            });
          </script>

      </ul>
      <?php
    echo '<div>';
     if($page > 1)
      {
       echo '<a id="prev"  > предыдущая страница</a>';
      }
     if($page < $total_pages)
      {
       echo '<a id="next" > следующая страница</a>';
      }
    echo '</div>';
   ?>


    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Можно ли как то в этом варианте доделать? Или придется все переделывать?

Comment: Очень не безопасный код. Старайтесь уходить от этого и использовать подготавливаемые запросы. И хоть немного учиться стоить логику. А не писать в стиле и так сойдет.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Но с чего начать исправлять код и что посмотреть или почитать?

Comment: Прочитать, что такое роутинг и подготавливаемые запросы, а также, что означает начальная точка входа. Чтобы не делать бесконечные инклуды и запуски сессий и т.д.